# How to reset a model field when creating a new instance via "Save As New"

Tags: django

Say I have a model w/ attribute special_id, I have the Save As New option enabled for the model's Admin, but when it creates the new instance I need to set special_id = None.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you share the implementation of this "Save As New" button?

Comment: Hi, It's enabled by adding save_as = True on the default model admin.